# json-patch wildcard usage in argocd manifest

Tags: jsonpath, json-patch, argocd

Is it possible to replace this

```
---
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: elastic-operator
  labels:
    argocd.application.type: "system"
spec:
  ignoreDifferences:
    - group: admissionregistration.k8s.io
      kind: ValidatingWebhookConfiguration
      jsonPointers:
        - /webhooks/0/clientConfig/caBundle
    - group: admissionregistration.k8s.io
      kind: ValidatingWebhookConfiguration
      jsonPointers:
        - /webhooks/1/clientConfig/caBundle
    - group: admissionregistration.k8s.io
      kind: ValidatingWebhookConfiguration
      jsonPointers:
        - /webhooks/2/clientConfig/caBundle
```

For something that uses a "wildcard" instead? The following is a "non-working" example of what I'm looking for:

```
---
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: elastic-operator
  labels:
    argocd.application.type: "system"
spec:
  ignoreDifferences:
    - group: admissionregistration.k8s.io
      kind: ValidatingWebhookConfiguration
      jsonPointers:
        - /webhooks/[*]/clientConfig/caBundle
```

I wasn't able to find anything in their doc that said that this is possible nor the opposite. i.e.https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/user-guide/diffing/
It seems that "json-patch" is being used but reading some of the RFCs, I was not able to find anything about wildcards either.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in case someone else faces this. The answer is no, json patch does not allow to use that expression. Luckly, [newer](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/diffing/#diffing-customization) versions of argocd enable the usage of json path (!=patch) by the new "jqPathExpressions":

```
data:
  resource.customizations: |
    admissionregistration.k8s.io/MutatingWebhookConfiguration:
      ignoreDifferences: |
        jqPathExpressions:
        - '.webhooks[]?.clientConfig.caBundle'
```